# filter for dates that fall in between start date and end date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a datetime column which I want to filter on two start date and end date parameters. however if the startd ate and end date are the same value no rows are returned.

```
ua.actiondate < '2013-10-08' and ua.actiondate  > '2013-10-08'

ua.actiondate between '2013-10-08' and '2013-10-08'
```

example values of my actionDate column

```
2013-10-08 12:30:17.000
2013-10-08 12:30:17.000
2013-10-08 12:31:56.000
2013-10-08 12:32:22.000
2013-10-08 12:35:35.000
2013-10-08 12:35:40.000
2013-10-08 12:35:40.000
2013-10-08 12:36:03.000
2013-10-08 12:36:44.000
2013-10-08 12:36:44.000
2013-10-08 12:36:54.000
```

as you can see the actionDate column is a date time object but the parameters are only dates.

Comment: None of these events happened on midnight of October 8th, 2013, so I would not expect any of them to be returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should [always use an open-ended date range](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) and [never use between](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

```
WHERE ua.actiondate >= @startdate AND ua.actiondate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @enddate);
```

This assumes `@startdate` and `@enddate` are always passed as dates with no time. If there is time involved (e.g. the app might pass `now()`) then you can round off using:

```
WHERE ua.actiondate >= CONVERT(DATE, @startdate)
  AND ua.actiondate <  CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @enddate));
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `2013-10-08 12:35:40.000` is greater than `2013-10-08` you have to use something like this

```
where ua.actiondate >= '2013-10-08' and ua.actiondate  < '2013-10-09'
```

Comment: is it possible to only filter on the date part?

Comment: @xerxes can you please elaborate? Do you mean your parameters might include time?

Comment: My query filters only on the date part. You could also extract the date part using `DATE()` but that will not use indexes on your table which makes it slow.

Comment: @juergend actually `CONVERT(DATE())` is the only function I know of that you can use against the column and still have a sargable clause. That doesn't make it a good practice, though. :-)